# Airflow on GCP - Errno 111 Connection refused

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

We have Airflow 1.10.5, using CeleryExecutor, running on Google Cloud Platform.

Occasionally, the following error happens:

```
[2019-12-17 19:00:45,990] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 704: Subtask our-task-name ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) [Errno 111] Connection refused
[2019-12-17 19:00:45,990] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 704: Subtask our-task-name This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
[2019-12-17 19:00:46,279] {{taskinstance.py:1051}} ERROR - Command '['gcloud', 'container', 'clusters', 'get-credentials', 'airflow-pipeline-name', '--zone', 'us-central1-a', '--project', 'project-name']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_container_operator.py", line 271, in execute
    "--project", self.project_id])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gcloud', 'container', 'clusters', 'get-credentials', 'airflow-pipeline-name', '--zone', 'us-central1-a', '--project', 'project-name']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2019-12-17 19:00:46,358] {{taskinstance.py:1082}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

Is it a bug in Airflow itself, in its plugins (like the plugin for Kubernetes) or in Google Cloud Platform?

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the metadata server was not responding at some moments. Our colleagues fixed this.